# How to pass a const object

Tags: c++, constants

I have a configuration class that I want to pass to another class (called Use) in a constructor.  I want to store the configuration class inside of the Use class as a private member variable.  I would like it to be const.

So far, I have this code:

```
class Configuration{
private:
    int value1_;
public:
    Configuration();
    Configuration(int value1){value1_=value1;}
    int value1() const {
        return value1_;
    }
};

class Use{
private:
    //const me
    Configuration config_;
    int something_;
public:
    Use(Configuration &config){
        config_=config;
    }

    void doSomething(){
        something_+=config_.value1();
    }
};
```

I want to const `Use::config_`, but every way that I try ends in confusing compile errors.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to support this is to use a reference

```
class Use{
private:
    const Configuration& config_;
    int something_;
public:
    Use(const Configuration &config) : 
      config_(config), 
      something_(0) {

    }

    void doSomething(){
        something_+=config_.value1();
    }
};
```

One item that needs to be a bit clearer in the question is the relationship between `Configuration` and `Use` instances.  If there is one `Configuration` which is meant to be shared amongst all `Use` instances then a reference (as I outlined) is the most appropriate choice.  In that scenario though you need to ensure that `Configuration` outlives all `Use` instances that take a reference to it.

On the other hand if `Configuration` is meant to be one per `Use` instance then a non-reference solution is probably more appropriate

Comment: It would be safer to take a copy, unless you can guarantee that the reference will remain valid after construction.

Comment: @MikeSeymour it's scenario dependent and there are definitely scenarios where having a copy is incorrect. Yes the user should clarify here though

Comment: @JaredPar, the copy is always appropriate while the reference often won't be. It's OK to point it out as an alternative but you really need to spell out the caveats.

Comment: @MarkRansom sorry, it's not always appropriate. You can definitely have a scenario where a single `Configuration` object is shared amongst several `Use` objects and they should always see the current value which can be updated.  In that case only a reference is appropriate and a copy will fall flat.

Comment: I'm marking this one as the answer because this discussion helps the reader weigh different options.  Thank you everyone for your help.  Ultimately, I just forget to add an initializer list.

Comment: @JaredPar, you make some good points but they really should be in the body of the answer. The blanket recommendation to use a reference will be wrong more often than it's right. Ah, I see you came to the same conclusion while I was typing this comment.

Comment: @MarkRansom i updated the answer to have a larger discussion about the choices

Answer (score 3):

Since the member is `const`, your constructor can't assign to it. However, it can initialise it directly from its initialiser list:

```
Use(Configuration const & config) : config_(config) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use initializers in constructor to assign a value to cons members

```
Use(Configuration &config)
: config_(config)
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `config` is being declared as a `const` member of your class you will be unable to modify it after it is created. That includes any attempts to assign a value to it other than within the member initialisation list. Also when you try to call any of its member functions on it that are not `const` you will get compiler errors. As you haven't posted the explicit errors I am guessing here that is possibly what you have as your example code calls a member function of that class on the instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to `const` but you can initialize it in the base member initializer list:

```
class Use{
private:
    const Configuration config_;
public:
    Use(const Configuration & config)
        : config_(config)
    {
    }
};
```